# Play! Java web framework. How does their development server compile automatically?

Tags: java, playframework

After looking at the Play! framework I find it really productive that the development server that it comes with automatically is able to compile .java files and show the changes, immediately. There's no hot deployer scanner that runs every tot seconds or so. The compilation happens when you hit refresh and it's extremely faster than my incremental `mvn package`. How do they do this?

I would like to know, well because I'm interested in knowing, but also because I don't want to use the entire Play! framework for my small project. I'm only interested in their development compilation process because I would like to adopt it :).

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Play Framework function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190606/how-does-the-play-framework-function)

Comment: OK, I've explained an important difference between Play's reloading and JRebel's reloading in the linked thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190606/how-does-the-play-framework-function/5907403#5907403

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was reading about this just this morning. It actually takes your changed **source** files and uses the Eclipse Java Compiler (ECJ) internally before spitting out the compiled files to the built-in dev server.

The thing is, you probably *don't* want to go to the effort of wiring the ECJ into your "small project".

You can definitely approximate it though - the trick is to **not** do a mvn package, instead you want to be dropping the changed .class files into your webapp's exploded warfile directory on the filesystem.

If you're not tied to a particular app server/container, have a look at the [Eclipse Jetty Plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin) - looks like it's what you need, and Jetty is **quick**

Comment: When I saw this question a while ago I was about to suggest the OP build something on top of Eclipse RCP for exactly the same reason but then saw the small project bit and thought better of it. Looks like the play devs had the same idea :)

Comment: I tried the Maven Jetty plugin, and it's no way as fast as the Play! framework (ECJ). I wonder if there's a servlet container out there that works with this Eclipse Java Compiler because it's amazingly fast.

Comment: Can I use Eclipse compiler with my existing servlet project?

Answer (score 4):

JDT -- Play! uses Eclipse JDT to compile and load classes dynamically. Much the same way you code in Eclipse and you see an error or warning messages as soon as you type in something not desirable. See [ApplicationCompiler](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.1.1/play/classloading/ApplicationCompiler.html) class.

You may also want to look into [JDT](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/overview.php).

Answer (score 3):

Play uses the Eclipse compiler to compile code at run-time.

Take a look at the following class, that is used by Play to perform the necessary compilation at run time.

https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/classloading/ApplicationCompiler.java

Answer (score 2):

The way they do it is by using a custom classloader that will detect changes to source files, use the Eclipse Java Compiler to compile the files and then hot swap the appropriate classes in the JVM. If you are looking for something similar, checkout ZeroTurnaround's [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/)
it is not free, but well worth the time savings when you need to redeploy a large project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Play developer however Struts2 is also capable of this but though the struts2-spring-plugin. Since the class reloading is provided by Spring it might be possible to use this spring feature by any project.

http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/spring-plugin.html
Search the page for "Class Reloading".

Comment: No not Struts, Struts 2 (S2). They are different products with different code bases. S2 is a pretty popular, modern (2008) Java MVC framework. With a feature set on par with Wicket and Spring MVC.