# Adding and Calling a JSP to a Running WebApplication

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications

Not sure if it possible or not

Once a WebApp is running, is it possible to add a new JSP to the Webcontent folder, and assuming you know the name of newly added JSP make a requst for this new JSP?

Edit: Adding more details

We have a Java Batch application that will generate JSP files with embeded Java Scriplets  e.g."<% Person.getName() %>". We want to be able to Run these JSP from within the web container to populate the javacode.

The only problem is that these JSP files are generated externally from the webapplication and we cannont restart the webapp everytime a new JSP is produced.

Answer (score 0):

As a WebApp is running AFTER you deploy the project in the server, any change made while the WebApp is running won't affect the project until you deploy the project again.

Comment: Thats what i'm seeing in my tests, and it does make sense. I was hoping that there might be a way around it.

Comment: @smeureej This isn't true. By using a combination of `bootstrap.jar` and eclipse debugger you can have hot reload enabled for your JSP container application. It's how Play Framework functions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190606/how-does-the-play-framework-function for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's possible, but the question is too broad to give a meaningful answer.

One example of such behavior, is running Apache Tomcat server in debug mode in Eclipse, but that's a very special case.

Comment: I will provide more details.